# Same JTextField for multiple classes and creating a search engine

Tags: java, search, boolean, actionlistener, jtextfield

I'm trying to use the same JTextField and the action listener that is with it for multiple classes. Even the GridBagConstraints I'd like to be in the same position. Is there an optimal way of doing this? The current way I am doing this is in the code below but when a user searches something,

```
//Home Class
static JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textField = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textField.gridwidth = 7;
    gbc_textField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_textField.fill = 2;
    gbc_textField.gridx = 2;
    gbc_textField.gridy = 1;
    homePane.add(textField, gbc_textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            SearchEngine.search();
        }
    });

//Method to return textfield for use in other classes
    public static JTextField textField() {
        return textField;
    }


//Game Class
static JTextField textField = Home.textField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.gridwidth = 5;
        gbc_textField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_textField.fill = 2;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 3;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 1;
        gamesPane.add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SearchEngine.search();
            }
        });

    //SearchEngine Class
    //In the SearchEngine class I have a series of if-statements to determine if the word searched is in the database.

setSearched(false);//resets the value of the boolean back to false. If a condition is met in the series of if statements, the value is set to true.
            if ((Home.textField().getText().equalsIgnoreCase("battlefield 4")){
                    || (Home.textField().getText().equalsIgnoreCase("bf4"))) {
                    setSearched(true);
                    setImageSource("bf4");
                    setURL("www.google.com");
                    setNumoURL(1);
                }
            }
        Run.runResult();//Runs the searched result
```

If the boolean is true, an image is displayed. If not, a JLabel saying "Not Found" is displayed...or is supposed to display. Currently the boolean is all over the place returning random values of true and false. I'm sorry if this is insufficient info, please comment below what else you'd like to know. In the end, I am trying to create a simple search engine for my application.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you might achieve this...

### You Could...

Create a custom field which sets itself up the way you want it to, including registering the `ActionListener`

The problem with this approach (personally), is you aren't actually adding any functionality to the field, you're just customizing the configuration, which seems a bit...worthless

### You Could...

Create a factory of some kind that could create a new instance of the search field, it could even be used to configure a pre existing instance of a `JTextField`.

```
JTextField searchField = SearchFieldFactory.newInstance();
// and/or
JTextFeld searchField = new JTextField();
SearchFieldFactory.configureSearchField(searchField);
```

See the [factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) for more details

### You Could...

Use some kind of builder to customise how the fields are created...

```
ActionListener searchListener = ...
JTextField field = new SearchFieldBuilder().
                       setColumns(10).
                       setActionListener(searchListener).
                       newInstance();
```

This would allow you to decide on how best the search field should be customised and define the default customisation as you see fit...

```
JTextField field = new SearchFieldBuilder().newInstance();
```

This is really great if 90% of the time you generate the same field, but want the flexibility to change it from time to time...

See the [builder pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) for more details

The constraints present another issue...

### You Could...

Provide some kind of factory which generated the constraints

```
JTextField searchField = SearchFieldFactory.newInstance();
gamesPane.add(searchField, SearchFieldUtilities.newSearchFieldConstraints());
```

Or simply added the specified text field to the specified container

```
JTextField searchField = SearchFieldFactory.newInstance();
SearchFieldUtilities.addToContainer(searchField, gamesPane);
```

Or have a factory that created the search field and adds it to the specified container....

```
SearchFieldUtilities.addNewSearchFieldTo(gamesPane);
```

You could then combine the creation of the search field with this method...

Or you could simply have a `static` instance of constraints stored somewhere.  `GridBagLayout` will make a local copy each time you apply the constraints, meaning you can actually modify them without effecting any components that were previous added with the same instance of the parent constraints

Personally, I'm generally not convinced by the idea of having the constraints predefined, but then again, I'm not facing your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create your custom JTextField

```
public class MyCustomTextField extends JTextField{

 //constructor 

// etc

}
```

Then you have to make your own Action listener or implement it directly to your jtf class and specify function as a parameter.

Bud i woud recomment you to make your own and override methods when using it;)

Create your own JTextField and use it for numerous classes by making instance of it.

> Even the GridBagConstraints I'd like to be in the same position. Is
>   there an optimal way of doing this?

Yes bud that depends on your code structure.And on what design you use.Im not really sure what you try to achieve from code that you posted so i cant tell you.Bud if you try to use some part of GUI that have same function and same visual in many *classes* or parts embed it into jpanel and use it high-level way.